# k number and distance for automating mesh network of electric service poles

Tags: nearest-neighbor, network-analysis, utility-network

I'm using QGIS to try to make an analysis for placing electric utilities poles for the first time. I've imported building and road info from OpenStreetMap and have tried some things with nearest hub and other strategies but not getting good results.

I need the poles to be placed on existing road way, and preferably reach a certain x distance (40m for the first run) to as many buildings as possible, and have them be spaced y distance apart from each other (45m). If there's an existing tool or process to do this it would be great to be able to plug in a sort of "pole resolution" to help minimize the number of poles over a selected area. Utimately the number of poles being placed is a big influence on cost and whether the project can go through, so that's why I'm looking for something that I can play with the k or other value to optimize that network.

This post seems to be close to what I'm looking for but it seems from other stack posts that there must be a better way of doing this.

Here is the village in question I'm trying to implement this on.

[image: Ajakurama]

Here is a previous project where there were already existing utility poles that we could work off of where I did a nearest hub to estimate cable needs.

[image]